# Can a wife accompany her husband in public?

Tags: family

Is it proper for a wife to accompany her husband in public when shopping or sightseeing?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe otherwise? It's certainly a day to day occurrence in every Muslim-majority country I've been to.

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: If not why are they married?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's perfectly fine. There are no Islamic texts that prohibit or discourage her accompanying him. The only conditions are that they behave decently in public (no public displays of affection/intimacy) and that they avoid places where evil/sins are present.